# Do I still need to use a service like DNSimple if I want a naked domain for my Heroku app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, dnsimple, namecheap

Researching past posts makes it seem like you have to use a service like DNSimple in order to have a naked domain (i.e. "example.com") for Heroku apps. I am wondering if that is still true, or if I can achieve this using only my app server.

I am using Namecheap BasicDNS and my app is a node/express app hosted on Heroku.

Thanks in advance for any tips. I am just trying to make sure before I purchase. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't point your apex domain to an hostname (hence to Heroku), [because you can't use a CNAME](https://blog.dnsimple.com/2014/01/why-alias-record/) for the apex.

Consequently, the only way to point your root domain to a service like Heroku is by using a DNS provider that provides a CNAME-like feature for the root domain, that is what DNSimple calls ALIAS.

You can also find more information in the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain).

Comment: Thank you Simone. I signed up for DNSimple and contacted support to see what I would need to do in order to have my apex domain display my heroku app. They said that I could do that with Namecheap, so I tried it and it is now working. It is my understanding, however, that since I now have a CNAME pointing my apex to a hostname (my Heroku app), I can't have any other CNAME records.

Comment: @Jake1986 FYI you can't use a CNAME for the apex, but you can have as many CNAMEs are you want, as long as they are for different names (and not for the APEX). It's possible there could have been a misunderstanding with support. :)